# Can't reach global addresses behind IPv6 router

Tags: routing, ipv6

I have IPv6 router based on Arch Linux. My ISP gives me **2a00:f480:4:266::/64** network:

```
# ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:24:af:04:66:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.20.10.134/16 brd 10.20.255.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute eth0
       valid_lft 42952sec preferred_lft 37552sec
    inet6 2a00:f480:4:266:7a24:afff:fe04:6672/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr 
       valid_lft 2591945sec preferred_lft 604745sec
    inet6 fe80::7a24:afff:fe04:6672/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b8:27:eb:c5:31:79 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.88.1/24 brd 192.168.88.255 scope global wlan0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2a00:f480:4:266::0388/64 scope global nodad 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::ba27:ebff:fec5:3179/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

My external interface is configured via `netctl`; for IPv4 I use **DHCP** and for IPv6 I use **SLAAC**:

```
# cat /etc/netctl/external 
Description='Wired WAN connection'
Interface=eth0
Connection=ethernet
IP=dhcp
IP6=stateless
DNS=('127.0.0.1' '::1')
SkipNoCarrier=yes
```

DNS server is `dnsmasq` installed locally. My internal interface is hand-configured:

```
# cat /etc/netctl/internal 
Description='Wireless LAN connection'
Interface=wlan0
Connection=ethernet
IP=static
IP6=static
Address='192.168.88.1/24'
Address6='2a00:f480:4:266::0388/64'
SkipNoCarrier=yes
```

I share internet connection to the whole room via `hostapd`. Forwarding is enabled:

```
# cat /etc/sysctl.d/30-ipforward.conf .
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
net.ipv6.conf.default.forwarding=1
net.ipv6.conf.all.forwarding=1
```

`iptables` is configured for both IP protocol versions:

```
# cat /etc/iptables/iptables.rules 
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:TCP - [0:0]
:UDP - [0:0]

# loopback functionality
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# drop all invalid packets regardless its origin
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
# allow established connections
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# allow ping from LAN
-A INPUT -i wlan0 -s 192.168.88.0/24 -p icmp --icmp-type 8 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
# allow TCP and UDP services
-A INPUT -p tcp --syn -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j TCP
-A INPUT -p udp -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j UDP
# deny all other incoming connections
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

# TCP services
-A TCP -i wlan0 -s 192.168.88.0/24 -p tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A TCP -i wlan0 -s 192.168.88.0/24 -p tcp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
# UDP services
-A UDP -i wlan0 -s 192.168.88.0/24 -p udp --dport 53 -j ACCEPT
-A UDP -i wlan0 -p udp --dport 67 -j ACCEPT

# allow forwarding between eth0 and wlan0
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
# deny all remaining
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-unreachable
COMMIT

*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [0:0]

# allow masquerading for LAN
-A POSTROUTING -s 192.168.88.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
COMMIT

# cat /etc/iptables/ip6tables.rules 
*filter
:INPUT DROP [0:0]
:FORWARD DROP [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [0:0]

# loopback functionality
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
# drop all invalid packets regardless its origin
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate INVALID -j DROP
# allow established connections
-A INPUT -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
# allow ICMPv6
-A INPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A OUTPUT -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -p ipv6-icmp -j ACCEPT
# allow forwarding between eth0 and wlan0
-A FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A FORWARD -i wlan0 -o eth0 -j ACCEPT
# deny all other incoming connections
-A INPUT -p udp -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited
-A INPUT -p tcp -j REJECT --reject-with tcp-reset
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp6-adm-prohibited
COMMIT
```

`radvd` is also installed and configured:

```
# cat /etc/radvd.conf 
interface wlan0 {
    AdvSendAdvert on;
    MinRtrAdvInterval 3;
    MaxRtrAdvInterval 10;

    prefix 2a00:f480:4:266::/64 {
        AdvOnLink on;
        AdvAutonomous on;
        AdvRouterAddr on;
    };

    RDNSS 2001:4860:4860::8888 2001:4860:4860::8844 {
    };
};
```

On my laptop in LAN I have IPv6 address from ISP's subnet (I assume via Router Advertisements):

```
[viktor@desolve-nettop ~]$ ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 78:24:af:04:66:72 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:45:20:c0:77:cc brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.88.10/24 brd 192.168.88.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 85645sec preferred_lft 85645sec
    inet6 2a00:f480:4:266:50d5:7ac7:d3b1:618f/64 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86396sec preferred_lft 14396sec
    inet6 fe80::40e2:4067:e8c6:3c1/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

However, [test-ipv6](https://test-ipv6.com), `ping` and `traceroute` of **ipv6.google.com** doesn't work on laptop in LAN:

```
[viktor@desolve-nettop ~]$ ping ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(li-in-x71.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
8 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 7103ms

[viktor@desolve-nettop ~]$ traceroute -6 ipv6.google.com
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2a00:f480:4:266::0388 (2a00:f480:4:266::0388)  121.853 ms  122.249 ms  122.224 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  * * *
21  * * *
22  * * *
23  * * *
24  * * *
25  * * *
26  * * *
27  * * *
28  * * *
29  * * *
30  * * *
```

At the same time all is great on router:

```
# ping ipv6.google.com
PING ipv6.google.com(li-in-x71.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from li-in-x71.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71): icmp_seq=1 ttl=45 time=16.4 ms
64 bytes from li-in-x71.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71): icmp_seq=2 ttl=45 time=16.4 ms
64 bytes from li-in-x71.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71): icmp_seq=3 ttl=45 time=16.3 ms
64 bytes from li-in-x71.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71): icmp_seq=4 ttl=45 time=16.3 ms
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
4 packets transmitted, 4 received, 0% packet loss, time 3004ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 16.313/16.359/16.434/0.047 ms

# traceroute -6 ipv6.google.com
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2a00:f480:4:266::1 (2a00:f480:4:266::1)  0.723 ms  0.621 ms  0.608 ms
 2  2a00:f480:0:3::4:ff (2a00:f480:0:3::4:ff)  0.667 ms  0.641 ms  0.626 ms
 3  2a00:f480:0:3::517:10 (2a00:f480:0:3::517:10)  1.133 ms  1.007 ms  0.882 ms
 4  2a00:f480:0:3::514:12 (2a00:f480:0:3::514:12)  0.773 ms  1.014 ms  0.889 ms
 5  2a00:f480:0:1:: (2a00:f480:0:1::)  1.203 ms  1.261 ms  1.205 ms
 6  m9-3-gw.msk.runnet.ru (2001:b08:b08:b08::f1)  0.690 ms  0.850 ms  0.768 ms
 7  2001:4860:1:1:0:cc3:0:1 (2001:4860:1:1:0:cc3:0:1)  0.922 ms  0.797 ms  0.832 ms
 8  2001:4860:0:116f::11 (2001:4860:0:116f::11)  1.315 ms 2001:4860:0:1170::2 (2001:4860:0:1170::2)  1.958 ms 2001:4860:0:1170::12 (2001:4860:0:1170::12)  1.155 ms
 9  2001:4860::c:4001:8e2d (2001:4860::c:4001:8e2d)  19.363 ms  17.405 ms 2001:4860::8:4000:e519 (2001:4860::8:4000:e519)  18.808 ms
10  2001:4860::2:0:752c (2001:4860::2:0:752c)  16.285 ms  14.465 ms  14.462 ms
11  * * *
12  * * *
13  * * *
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  * * *
18  * * *
19  * * *
20  li-in-x71.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4010:c05::71)  18.411 ms  17.802 ms  16.240 ms
```

`ip6tables` rules doesn't block requests, forwarding is enabled and I don't know why it doesn't work. The same true for my Android phone. Can anyone help me to find the cause of the problem? I've found the same issue [here](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=233881) but with no solution

Here is my routing table on laptop in LAN:

```
[viktor@desolve-nettop ~]$ ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2a00:f480:4:266::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto ra metric 600 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev tun0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev wlp2s0 proto kernel metric 600 pref medium
default via fe80::ba27:ebff:fec5:3179 dev wlp2s0 proto ra metric 20600 pref medium
```